# Activity sometimes does not restart in android

Tags: android, android-activity

The following code downloads some files(video and images). Once the files are downloaded the activity is made to restart to complete the reloading process. The problem is that the activity sometimes does not restart even though it shows the message correctly. This seems to happen when a video is playing.

```
public class FastFTPDownloader extends DownloaderBase {

    public FastFTPDownloader(Activity activity, Intent intent) {
        super(activity, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(true);
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FTPFile[] files = null;
        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
        try {
            client.connect(params[0]);
            client.login(params[1], params[2]);
            client.changeDirectory(params[3]);
            File alphalist = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH + "list.txt");
            File betalist = new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH + "list.txt");

            // Step 1: download list.txt to alpha folder
            client.download("list.txt", alphalist);
            Log.d("Pankaj " + this.getClass().toString(),
                    "Downloading list.txt");

            // Step 2: compare list.txt in alpha with list.txt in beta
            // if both are same size return and do nothing
            if (betalist.length() == alphalist.length()) {
                // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
                Log.d("Pankaj " + this.getClass().toString(),
                        "Nothing to download");
                return "Nothing to download";
            }
            // Step 3: get a list of files from the server
            files = client.list();
            // for each file in list if file exists move on to next file
            for (FTPFile f : files) {
                File betafile = new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH + f.getName());
                if (betafile.exists()) {
                    if (betafile.length() == f.getSize()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                // Step 4: the file does not exist in beta so download to alpha
                // if it is not there
                File alphaFile = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH + f.getName());
                if (alphaFile.exists()) {
                    // if files are same size move on to next file.
                    if (alphaFile.length() == f.getSize()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // if existing file is less than the remote file continue
                    // download
                    // for files having size > remote file do a complete
                    // download.
                    if (alphaFile.length() < f.getSize()) {
                        client.download(f.getName(), alphaFile,
                                alphaFile.length());
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                client.download(f.getName(), alphaFile);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (FTPException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (FTPDataTransferException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (FTPAbortedException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (FTPListParseException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            // FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        File alpha = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH);
        File beta = new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH);

        File[] betaFiles = beta.listFiles();

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Restarting Please Wait...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        // Step 5: shutdown the activity to complete the reconfiguration
        VideoView video = ConfigLoader.getVideo();
        if (video.isPlaying()) {
            video.stopPlayback();
        }
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        activity.finish();
        // ConfigLoader.getResources().reload();
        // Step 6: if the file is not in list then delete it from beta
        for (File f : betaFiles) {
            if (!existsInList(f.getName())) {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
        File[] alphaFiles = alpha.listFiles();
        // Step 7: move the remaining files in alpha to beta.
        for (File f : alphaFiles) {
            moveToBeta(f);
        }

        // Step 8: restart the application with new configurations.
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return "Activity Restarted Successfully";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        FastFTPDownloader.setDoing(false);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    private void moveToBeta(File file) {
        File betaFile = new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH + file.getName());
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(betaFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            file.delete();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the downloaderbase code:-

```
public abstract class DownloaderBase extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected Activity activity;
    protected Intent intent;
    private static boolean doing = false;

    public static boolean isDoing() {
        return doing;
    }

    public static void setDoing(boolean doing) {
        DownloaderBase.doing = doing;
    }

    public DownloaderBase(Activity activity, Intent intent) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    protected void deleteSubFolders(String uri) {
        File currentFolder = new File(uri);
        File files[] = currentFolder.listFiles();

        if (files == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                deleteSubFolders(f.toString());
            }
            // no else, or you'll never get rid of this folder!
            f.delete();
        }
    }

    protected void copyFromBeta() throws IOException {
        File beta = new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH);
        File alpha = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH);
        File[] files = beta.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            String fname = f.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (!fname.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!existsInList(f.getName())) {
                continue;
            }
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            File copy = new File(alpha + f.getName());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }

    protected void trimAlpha() {
        File alpha = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH);
        File[] files = alpha.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            if (!existsInList(f.getName())) {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    protected boolean existsInList(String filename) {
        File list = new File(ConfigLoader.ALPHA_PATH + "list.txt");
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(list);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (s.equals(filename)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

main activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
    private Handler h;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Standee standee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        standee = new Standee(this, vv, iv);
        standee.start();

        h = new Handler();
        h.post(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!FastFTPDownloader.isDoing()) {
            h.removeCallbacks(this);
            FastFTPDownloader ftp = new FastFTPDownloader(this, getIntent());
            ConfigLoader l = ConfigLoader.getInstance();
            ftp.execute(l.URL(), l.User(), l.Password(), l.Path());
            h.postDelayed(this, l.Delay() * 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        player = standee.getMediaPlayer();
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. I am using FTP4j library if that is needed.

Comment: may be write that code in onresume() method i think it will call

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the activity is being destroyed and re-created by Android.  Thus the reference that your AsyncTask has to the activity becomes invalid.  There is a pattern to address this.

1. In your AsyncTask, provide an "attach" method:

   public void attach(Activity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
   }
2. In your activity class, alway hook up the current version of the activity to the task as follows:

   static AsyncTask myTask = ....

and in onCreate() or onResume()

```
if (myTask != null) myTask.attach(this);
```

Comment: I have added the mainactivity code to the question. I am using a handlerto check for downloads. When I create a downloader object I pass an activity object to it. I use that object to manipulate the restarting.